# Field values that vary over time and querying them

Tags: sql, date

Imagine you have a website which lists available hotel rooms and their prices.
The hotel owners set a price per day for each room - it only needs to be as complicated as "Jan 1st costs $100" not "Jan 1st 1999 costs $50, Jan 1st 2000 costs $100".
The granularity is limited to day-rate.

What would be the most efficient (in terms of load when querying for rooms) way to represent this in a database?
For each room, have a separate table holding a date field and a price field? ie 365 entries per room.

I see ways to solve this, but the problem becomes slightly more complicated when for example a user wishes to do a query such as "7 days in august with a budget of $500". This is a feature I would dearly like to implement.

The UI will allow owners to set room prices as blocks of time rather than individual day rates - eg if a room price was $50 for jan-jun and $100 for jul-dec then that is two price blocks. Obviously if needs be that could be translated into 365 date type fields, but a solution using two daterange type fields instead would be preferable.

Any pointers as to where I could learn techniques for this would be greatly appreciated. I have searched google and found information on Calendar Tables, but any additional tips or info would be appreciated.

Historically I have used MySQL, but anything would be considered.

Comment: I think this is a little harsh. I am attempting to do research, but when one doesn't know the correct terminology for a problem, it can be very hard to find information, especially when it involves words such as "date" that are likely to return vast numbers of hits in google etc.

Answer (score 1):

In the terminology of Ralph Kimball, this is called a slowly changing dimension.

I would suggest that you look at one of this books.  The latest edition of "The Data Warehouse Toolkit" should cover this topic quite well.

Comment: Thankyou for your input.
I am doing some research on SCDs now, but am unsure if this is really a match for my issue as it seems to be to do with Data Warehousing whereas I am talking about a live database.
Are DW techniques such as this not more about reporting (historical data going into the past) rather than live data (ie what the room price _will be_ rather than what it _was_)? Are they not going to be a little "expensive" (ie in CPU cycles etc) for queries such as this to be run potentially tens of thousands of times a day?